# Spearman's Rho for Dependent Samples Measured at Time Windows

Tags: time-series, correlation, nonparametric, spearman-rho

I have conducted a study where I have collected dependent data (not i.i.d) from 10 participants, measuring variables X and Y from the participants at various time-windows. Thus I have n=350, for variables X and Y.

I want to perform a correlation analysis for X and Y I have collected, over all of the 350 data points. What would be most appropriate tool for statistical analysis?

As the data is non-normal, I (perhaps wrongly) assumed that Spearman's Rho would be correct. Indeed, colleagues have some doubts.

Comment: So you have 10 participants, each measured at 35 times ?  And then you want, what?, one correlation for each participant ?  Or something else ? If you were to plot what you are looking for, what would you put on the *x*-axis and *y*-axis ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico I've have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: I would suggest a mixed model with covariate $X$, response variable $Y$, and an individual random intercept to handle differences among participants. Non-normality can be checked by looking at the residuals of the model. If you have something with very little chance of being normal (e.g. binary data) then you should try to use the appropriate distribution Y.

Comment: I'd second the suggestion from @MaximilianAigner . .... Unless, if you want to keep with simple correlation, you might perform correlations within each participant or within each time point. ... It might be possible to simply pool all 350 observations and perform a correlation analysis. It depends on what you are measuring, and what you want to determine.